# What type of construct is this in ruby?

Tags: ruby

This is an excerpt from the ruby Koans.

```
in_ruby_version("mri") do
    RubyConstant = "What is the sound of one hand clapping?"
    def test_constants_become_symbols
      all_symbols_as_strings = Symbol.all_symbols.map { |x| x.to_s }

      assert_equal true, all_symbols_as_strings.include?(:RubyConstant)
    end
 end
```

What is this method without any modifier in front of the in_ruby_verion ? What is this construct.

Comment: `in_ruby_version("mri")` accepts a block argument (enclosed in the `do`-`end` pair). The code inside of `in_ruby_version("mri")` would have a `yield` statement which then would yield to that block.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually just a method call. What makes it interesting is that it is being passed a block, (the `do`  `end` notation).